# Inserting data from different dbs table to another db in the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `table 1` in the `db1` and `table 2` in the `db2`.  I want to insert the `table1` and `table2` data into `table3` which is in the `db3` structure of all three tables is same and all dbs on same server.

Can any one help how to do that using insert statement?

Comment: And what is the problem? Just fully qualify the table names...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MS SQL Server and db1, db2 and db3 "structures" are different databases:

```
USE db3
INSERT INTO table3
SELECT  CombinedTables.[Alias1], CombinedTables.[Alias2]
(
    SELECT col1 AS [Alias1], col2 AS [Alias2] FROM db1.[schema, <dbo>].table1
    UNION
    SELECT col1, col2 FROM db2.[schema, <dbo>].table2
) AS CombinedTables
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use db3
Go

INSERT INTO Table3
select * from 
(
select * from db1..Table1
union all
select * from db2..Table2
) a
```